# Agnostically convert spreadsheet to csv file

Tags: python-3.x, file, csv, xlsx, ods

I have a script that takes a csv and does something with it.
I'd like this script to be agnostic to the spreadsheet file type (xlsx, xls, ods for instance), and always convert the file to csv for processing. Is there a way to do this without corrupting the data in any way?

Comment: No, the script must necessarily handle the specifics of each format.

Comment: Does it have to be as a Python library? There are command line tools that can do that conversion semi-reliably, which you can append inside a BASH script or something similar. For example, a headless version of LibreOffice.

Comment: I'm open to any solution--it doesn't have to be python

Answer (score 1):

You can use a headless version of the open-source software, [Libreoffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/), to convert the same extensions that Libreoffice can normally do within in the GUI. This solution does require you to install the whole office suite which may be overkill depending on your particular situation.

However, via the command line, you can call Libreoffice to do this conversion:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to csv <input_file> --outdir </path/to/dir>
```

This example is under the assumption that you are using a Unix-like machine, however there should be a similar version for Windows as well (e.g. `soffice.exe`). Replace the `<input_file>` with your file name and the `</path/to/dir/>` to the path to the directory you want to have your output (the output directory option is opional). You can use the wildcard `*` as the input file, which would convert all the files in the directory to csv.